# Nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate after I deleted the certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, openssl, lets-encrypt

I generated an SSL certificate on one of my subdomains. I then tried to `delete/revoke` the certificate using the command `certbot delete`. A little terminal menu popped up asking me what certificate I would like to delete. I deleted the one I wanted to delete. Now, when running `sudo nginx -t` I am getting error messages saying:

`nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/app.mydomain.nl/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory`

I guess the `certbot delete` command did not fully delete the certificate or something? I am clueless what to do right now...

Comment: Use `sudo nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire Nginx configuration across all included files. Identify the `server` block which references the non-existent file and either remove it or modify it.

Answer (score 5):

You probably used the command `$ certbot --nginx` and your nginx config file was edited to look for the certificate:

```
server{
    server_name [your_domain];

    location /static {
        ...
    }

    location / {
        ...
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[...]; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/[...]; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/[...]; # managed by Certbot

}

server{
    if ($host = [your_domain]) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name [your_domain];
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

The `$ certbot delete` will not change it back, so you have to delete the part related to the certificated and change the `server_name` to your ip address, so it will look like:

```
server{
    server_name [your ip];

    location /static {
        ...
    }

    location / {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: can you to the point how to solve ? i didnt understand what do you mean for solving

Comment: in my nginx there is no manage by certbot i have migration from apache to nginx , but the error always on apperas sad ;(

Answer (score 4):

Comment or remove these lines

```
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[...]; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/[...]; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/[...]; # managed by Certbot
```

in all files available in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`

Comment: To be more precise, one should look in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled since configuration files there are the ones that are "active".